# PHP and MySQL - inserting columns depending upon non-empty form fields

Tags: php, sql, forms, insert

As the title says, I'm trying to insert a row into a MySQL table using data sent in an HTML form. Some of the form fields can be left blank, however. Previously, for a select statement, I did this loop to check what fields were not empty and form an SQL query string (just for illustration), where $sql is a statment like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE":

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
if( $i != $size - 1 ) {
    if( !empty($formData[$i]) ) {
        $sql = $sql . " {$formFields[$i]} LIKE \"%{$formData[$i]}%\" and"; 
    }
} else {
    if( !empty($formData[$i]) ) {
        $sql = $sql . " {$formFields[$i]} LIKE \"%{$formData[$i]}%\";"; 
    }
    else {
        $sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql)-4 ) . ";"; 
    }
}
```

}

However in this case now, some of the insert fields can be blank, where previously it didn't matter because I was doing a "SELECT *" and I only had to worry about the WHERE clause. Is there an easier way to do this, other than having a monster of a for loop?

Comment: i'm confused ... why do you need to `select` anything when you want to an insert?

Comment: You can insert blanks into columns in MySQL. What's the issue? What do you want to do with blanks?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array that where the keys are the names of the fields, you could probably get away with a smaller for loop and less if conditionals. Once you do the data cleansing on $_POST you could do something like...

```
    foreach($formFields as $key => $value) {
        if(!empty($formFields)) {
            // build your query
        }
    }
```

As far as not looping through all the form fields, there's probably not a faster way to do it. I suppose you could use an array function like array_walk to iterate through all the fields you have available to you. You'd still have to go through every element in the array though...

Comment: There might be stuff in the form fields that's not relevant to the query itself. IMO it's better to loop through the columns to query against and see if they're present in the user-submitted data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a foreach loop. It's what they're for and they will make your code a lot easier to understand. Loop through all the columns that you may or may not query against, and add them if they're present in $_POST/$_GET.

Here's my general strategy for composing queries like this:

```
<?php

$formFields = validate( $_REQUEST ); // PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE VALIDATE/ESCAPE YOUR DATA

// You should also normalize HTML name fields to actual MySQL column names, if they're different

// Columns you may or may not want to query
$columns = array( 'foo', 'bar', 'buzz' );

$where = array();
foreach( $columns as $column )
{
  if( ! empty($formFields[$column]) )
  {
    $where[] = "$column = {$formFields[$column]}";
  }
}

$where = implode( ' AND ', $set );

$sql = "SELECT * FROM t WHERE $where";
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build 2 strings at the same time, one for the field list and one for the value list.

```
$fields = [];
$values = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        if( !empty($formData[$i]) ) {
            array_push($fields,$formFields[$i]);
            array_push($values,$formData[$i]);
        }
    }
} 
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(`".implode("`,`",$fields)."`) VALUES('".implode("','",$values)."')";
```

This of course assumes you have at least one non-blank field and have taken the necessary precautions to prevent injection.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, watch out for Little Bobby Tables: [xkcd.com/327/](http://xkcd.com/327/)  Building sql strings like that is disastrous.  What you are looking for (and will make debugging easier) is parameterized queries.

Start here: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)